# Android add badgets for TabLayout tabs

Tags: android

i'm trying to implementing this feature on my application by this library [jgilfelt/android-viewbadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger), i read some problem about this feature on this links [Add badge to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537544/add-badge-to-tab) and [Android Tablayout tabs with notification badge like whatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31968162/6599627): but i cant do that

I found this class as implementing this feature as [helper class](https://gist.github.com/eneim/55df01e092520a6d33a4), but i can use that

on my code as:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentMainMarkets(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentMainMarkets(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentMainMarkets(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DefaultTransformer());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    /* Add Badget for tabs */
    TabLayout.Tab tab       = tabsLayout.getTabAt(0);
    TextView     txt = new TextView(context);
    txt.setText("(9)");
    tab.setCustomView(txt);
    badge = new BadgeView(context, txt);

}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList      = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String>   mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implementing this screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved and whats solution about that?

```
LayoutInflater inflater            = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View   badget_t = inflater.inflate(R.layout.badget_t, null);
TabLayout.Tab  tab                 = tabsLayout.getTabAt(0);
tab.setCustomView(badget_t);
badge = new BadgeView(context, badget_t);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

`badget_t` layout:

```
<com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="{fa-arrow-right}"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### I would suggest you look at this website:

https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

this is very helpfull for me